# Loading less with SystemJS in Angular2 or Angular4

Tags: angular, less, systemjs

I'm working on a Angular 2 project with SystemJS and I'm using less for styling my components.
I'm also using a plugin library (systemjs-less-plugin) to load and compile the less files.

I haved noticed that the scripts are not loaded and I can't understand why.

Here is my systemjs.config:

```
 /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            application: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',

            'css': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-css',
            'less': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-less',
            'lesscss': 'npm:less'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            lesscss: {
                main: {
                    browser: './dist/less.min.js',
                    node: '@node/less'
                }
            },
            css: {
                main: 'css.js'
            },
            less: {
                main: 'less.js'
            }
        },
        meta: {
            '*.less': { loader: 'less' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Of course I have posted the question in the github of the library too...

Comment: did you get any solution to this issue, as i am facing exactly the same.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( We have given up the use of less.